# Passing an array of items to backend

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs

Hi question regarding my codes.

I am trying to pass an array of images to backend.

imageUpload function returns an array of images uploaded to cloudinary. The array is then passed to a postDataAPI function which posts/sends it to the server ( Node Js).

However, in my server, I only get the value of the first item of the array.

What am I missing here?

Edit: Added postman test

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. try testing it on postman if the same thing happens
2. Make sure you don't have any middleware that filters it out

Comment: I have tried it already on postman and it is working.  And there is no other middleware other than user authentication/ jwt verification.

Comment: If it works on postman, then that means the issue is in your client code.  Are you using fetch or axios?

Comment: or perhaps you have your own "API" handling and you're filtering it on your "post"?

Comment: I am using axios. I have only configured the default options of axios, adding a default url and added credentials. There is no filtering in my api.